# Rendering null values in vertical Classic Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have migrated my application from Oracle APEX 5.1 to 20.2.
I have a classic report (showing 1 record) that uses the predefined template type "Vertical Report". I use it to show the details of the recording. NULL columns are not rendered after migration. I can't find a suitable setting (in 5.1 nullcolumns are rendered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try to set

- region's type to "Classic report"
- template: "Standard"
- (under region's **attributes**)

  - template: **Value attribute pairs - column**

I checked, NULLs are rendered.

Comment: The "Vertical Report" is a template that is visible when "Template Type" = "Predefined". It indeed does not render NULL columns. Maybe this template is a valid alternative.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately in version 5.1 null columns were rendered.

Comment: You mean region's attributes or report's attributes? temlate 'Value Attribute Pairs' can be choose in report's region. It look different but it works.

Comment: As I wrote, "region attributes" & as you said: it looks different, but it *works* :)